# How to find readable folders on linux

Tags: php, linux, shell, find, readable

i m trying to find all readable directories and subdurectories on Linux server using shell command ,
i have tried this command line:

```
find /home -maxdepth 1 -type d -perm -o=r
```

but this command line show me just the readable folders in (`/`)  directories and not subdirectories too.

I want to do that using php or command line

thank you

Comment: If you want subdirectories, just remove `-maxdepth 1`

Comment: good idea i find list of directories when apply this command line but when i want to access or read this directori it tell me that ( Can't open this folder! )


is ther any idea to do it with php script like jumping or somthing like that

Comment: Its good idea to mark answers as correct and not posting comments as answers -> ~http://stackoverflow.com/a/37220868/797495  . I may want to delete those "answers" or you'll get downvoted ;)

Comment: Sir excuse me cuz im new hear

Comment: NP, we like to keep SO organized, so future users gets proper help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "***but this command line show me just the readable folders in ( / )
>   directories and not subdirectories too***"

When you set `-maxdepth 1` you're restricting the find command to `/home` only, **remove it** to allow find to search **recursively**.

```
find /home -type d -perm -o=r
```

---

If you need a native `php` solution, you can use this `glob_recursive` function and `is_writable`, i.e.:

```
<?php
function rglob($pattern, $flags = 0) {
    $files = glob($pattern, $flags);
    foreach (glob(dirname($pattern).'/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR|GLOB_NOSORT) as $dir) {
        $files = array_merge($files, rglob($dir.'/'.basename($pattern), $flags));
    }
    return $files;
}

$dirs = rglob('/home/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
foreach( $dirs as $dir){
    if(is_writable($dir)){
        echo "$dir is writable.\n";
    }
}
```